# Not able to make changes to modules (Python build directory)

Tags: python, build

I made a change to the file structure of my package. I renamed one of the folders that contains a module to 'build'.
I later encountered some problem in the app. So I switched the directory back to what it was named before ('controller').

Now, whenever I run the application, I see that outdated code is being executed.
A traceroute shows this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/www/SkillsPlanner/trunk/controller/modules/Controller.py", line 185, in loadBuildInfo
wget.get(resource.get('url'), output_folder=self.params.get('working_dir'), singledownload=True)
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/downloader/modules/wget.py", line 672, in get
filerelpath = download(resourceurl, out=output_folder)", 
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/downloader/modules/wget.py", line 572, in download
raise WgetException("Tmp folder (" + str(APP['tmp_folder']) + ") is not writable")
WgetException: Tmp folder (./tmp) is not writable
```

I have since made a change to the signature of the download function in the wget module.
The package does no longer contain a 'build' directory, and there is no 'build/bdist.linux-x86_64' folder, either.

So what is happening here? All changes that I make to the wget module have no effect.
When removing the .pyc files from the project, I see that the files are not being compiled.
It's as if it's loaded from another location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue:
There was a distribution located at usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MyPackage.egg
Removing this file fixed the problem.